# Displaying the loop counter in Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I have created a for loop for iterating excel files in automation anywhere. It contains 60000 rows. I want to print the counter value for each iteration of for loop. Message Box option is taking too much time. Is there any efficient way other than Message Box? My code is as follows..

```
Start Loop "Each row in an Excel dataset of session: Default"
    Message Box : "$Counter$"
End Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Log To File` command as a light-weight logging system, preferably in a `.txt` file as it's faster. Just make sure you mark the checkbox stating 'append'.

Sidenote: Have you considered using your Excel file into as data source? With an Excel file of this magnitude, it's a lot more efficient to use the `Database` command to iterate over your data. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SISeZi1IsKg) is a video showcasing how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend using Excel at a database as showcased by Roel's link. Allows you to connect to an excel file, perform a SQL query such as

`COUNT (*) from [sheet1$]`

Of note here, the sheet is how you call an excel sheet as a table. To call it as a variable, you would do `[$sheetName$$]`

If you wanted to work with specific columns where a header is present, it is a best practice to wrap the column names with ticks `, left of the 1 key on the keyboard. This is required for table names with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

best practise would be creating a check sheet as you go around loop 
create a log file with counter and time stamp 
(i use "Success" as a setcell command if there is a no error at the end of one loop)

and

error log with excel row number and screenshot of the error

Refer to excel system variable [ExcelSytemVariable purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eNrg.png)